# Navbar component not displaying react-bootstrap CSS

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I am rendering a react-bootstrap navbar but I am just getting jumbled text with none of the bootstrap styles.

I have the bootstrap CDN tag. I have installed react-bootstrap to the project with npm. I also made sure not to use the Bootstrap 4 tag, as home have said that doesn't work with react-bootstrap I added this following lines to index.html as instructed here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.js" crossorigin />

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.js"
  crossorigin
/>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin
/>

<script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
```

I also tried all of the posted solutions for this problem that I could find. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Index.html (Only the script tags obviously)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.js" crossorigin />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
            Dank memes
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post your entire index.html file? It looks like you're missing a div with an id of 'root'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong bootstrap version (3.3.7) in your `index.html` file. You need to use (4.3.1):

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

I was able to reproduce it incorrectly with 3.3.7 [image]
And reproduce what looks like the correct way using (4.3.1): [image]

Comment: Thank you. I must have read outdated advice regarding "don't use bootstrap 4 with react-bootstrap".